# What's different between two constructors?

Tags: kotlin

What different between this type of constructor?

```
class ColorsArray(context: Context) {}
```

and

```
class ColorsArray(var context: Context){}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second class not only declares a constructor that takes a `Context`, but it also has a property named `context` where it saves the value passed into the constructor. You can then access this like so:

```
val colorsArray = ColorsArray(context)
println(colorsArray.context)
```

Since you've declared it as a `var` and not a `val`, this can also be reassigned.

```
colorsArray.context = someOtherContext
```

Properties declared in the primary constructor are covered in the docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case constructor takes a `context` parameter and does nothing with it.

In the second case the code example provided:

```kotlin
class ColorsArray(var context: Context) { }
```

is a shortcut for:

```kotlin
class ColorsArray(context: Context) {
    var context: Context = context
}
```